# Visual Studio Code, open file shortcut for double click

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> keyboard shortcut to navigate between files.  However when I select a file and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it opens file in the existing tab with italics on the title.  If I select another file using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> and press enter it opens the other file on the same tab.  Is there a keyboard shortcut to open the file in a new tab instead of the same tab?

Comment: New editor tab, right? There is an option to open files in a split screen style. Are you looking for that?

Comment: not split screen, open a new tab instead of opening everything in the same tab.  I know there is a global setting for this, but I want to do this on a per-file basis using keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Tab... as in like this? https://imgur.com/a/aPKeF

Comment: The default ctrl+, opens up user settings.  Did you reset it to something else?  Hard to help without being able to reproduce your steps.  Or did an extension change that keybinding?

Answer (score 39):

```
"workbench.list.openMode": "doubleClick"
```

Comment: It is not a problem it is just user preferences, some users want to double click the file in the IDE "VS Code" to preview the file, to achieve this go to "settings.json" file and set "workbench.list.openMode" to  "doubleClick"

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't higher voted as it was the correct answer for me

Comment: Another useful option to note is `"workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": false` - this fully opens all files that you search for using "go to file" (Ctrl+P/Cmd+P).

Comment: Thanks for saving me. "Single click open" of vscode doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 25):

As you have seen, when you single-click a file it previews it in the current tab and you have to double-click it to open it properly for editing. You can disable this behaviour by going into Code's settings and specifying:

```
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false
```

...in your user settings.

Comment: What if I want to make that file not in preview mode without changing that setting? What is the shortcut for that?

Comment: This worked for me. thank you

Comment: Thank you, disabling "Workbench" › "Editor: Enable Preview" worked for me. Just setting "workbench.list.openMode" to "false" was not working.

Answer (score 13):

> What if I want to make that file not in preview mode without changing that setting? What is the shortcut for that?

- You can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, aka the *save* command. There is nothing to save, but it does what you require.

This can trigger reload actions in some development file servers, however. There are two more ways that I found, slightly more laborious:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>: Close tab, reopen tab. No more in preview state. But this will make you lose your undo history for the file. (Edit in 2020: Not anymore, as undo history is now preserved even after file close. But of course some plugin logic might be affected by it)
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>PgUp</kbd>(, <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>PgDown</kbd>): Move the tab one to the left and optionally back to the right again. Not sure if these keybindings are the default ones, but you get the idea.
- Type something and undo
- Move the tab into another editor group (and optionally back again). Example: `View: Move Editor into Right Group`, then `View: Move Editor into Left Group`. You could even make this a macro and assign it to a custom shortcut.
- `View: Pin Editor`, `View: Unpin Editor`. Has the side effect of moving the tab to the very left
- any more..?

Answer (score 1):

The (default?) shortcut for the command that you want (That is the `Keep open`/`View: Keep Editor` command) is `CTRL+K Enter`

To see your shortcut open the command panel (CTRL+(shift)+P by default) and type the following command: `>View: Keep Editor`

[image]

You can also right-click the editor tab and near the bottom there should be the command `Keep Open` with the (default) shortcut next to it.

[image]

These commands allow you to 'keep the current tab open when navigating to a new file'. Doesn't match your requirement for the full 100% but for me it works wonders :-)