# How to open file with double click in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

By default if you navigate in `Solution Explorer` and just point on some file `Visual Studio` immediately open this file for editing. I would like to change this behavior and open files with double click

Like written here (but it for VS Code)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57233522/5709159

How to change this settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "Solution Explorer", click on "Preview Selected Items".
[image]